# Why table cell which could fit into 32px height grow over specified height?

Tags: html, css

**SOLVED**.

This is an example:

HTML:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr style="height: 100%;">
      <td class="lefttd">
        <a href="#mmenu" style=""><img src="http://www.numbeo.com/images/Menu1.svg"></a>
      </td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="righttd"><img src="http://www.online-utility.org/icons/gear_64.png" style="margin-right: 0.5em;">Online-Utility.org </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  border-spacing: 0;
  background-color: #bcf;
  width: 100%;
}

table > tr, table > tr > td {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

.lefttd {
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.righttd {
  width: 95%;
  height: 32px;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 30px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

a.mmenu {
  border: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #aaa;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
}

img {
  width: 32px;
  border: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/adamovic/sw6c3z91/

In Chrome I see this table computed with height 35px... What causes this table to grow height more than 32px and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `vertical-align: middle;` to your image

```
<img src="http://www.online-utility.org/icons/gear_64.png" style="width: 32px; margin-right: 0.5em; vertical-align: middle;">
```

Also, you shouldn't be inlining styles like this.  It's a terrible practice.  Uses classes and stylesheets instead.

Edit: you can try a few other values too.  It looks like `vertical-align:bottom` might work even better.  It appears with the font size and line height that that will get you closer to 32px.  With middle it's at about 33px

Comment: works for me, the 33px comes from the boder-bottom of 1px

Comment: @Restros Cool.  Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved. I haven't properly marked to `img` `vertical-align: middle` and also `padding: 0` to `tr/td`.